# Require env - Nginx alternative

Tags: nginx

Hello I have this Apache config , which doing follow:
Allow access to /api if visitor come from 192.168.0.0/24 or have referer www.domain.com , if neither match then ask for password.

```
<Location /api/>
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName 'Restricted Access'
        AuthUserFile /htpasswd/password
        Require valid-user
        SetEnvIf Referer www\.domain\.com allow_referer
        Require env allow_referer
        Require ip 192.168.0.0/24
        Require all denied
        ProxyPass http://127.0.0.15/
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.15/ </Location>
</Location>
```

I need same thing for Nginx. This is what I have currently, but cannot find way how to whitelist if match the referer

```
location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.15/;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_connect_timeout  180s;
        proxy_send_timeout  180s;
        proxy_read_timeout  180s;
        satisfy any;
        allow 192.168.0.0/24;
        auth_basic "Protected Area";
        auth_basic_user_file /htpasswd/password;
        deny all;
}
```

Comment: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_referer_module.html#valid_referers

Comment: I reviewed before valid_referers , but didn't find out how to get desired effect.

Comment: I guess this should be combined with auth_request

Comment: Anyone can help with example? Still cannot get any success :( ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found solution which is equivalent to Apache.

```
location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.15/;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_connect_timeout  180s;
        proxy_send_timeout  180s;
        proxy_read_timeout  180s;

        satisfy any;
        allow 192.168.0.0/24;
        deny all;
        auth_request /check-referer;
        auth_basic "Protected Area";
        auth_basic_user_file /htpasswd/password;
}

location = /check-referer {
        internal;
        valid_referers www.domain.com;
        if ($invalid_referer) { return 401; }
        return 200;
}
```

@Alexey Ten, thank you for guidance.